# How to use kbhit() with delay without waiting

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, delay, kbhit

**I am making a program in which i have an infinite loop. I used kbhit() to detect whether a key is pressed or not. I am also using delay in the loop. So the problem is if i press the key i have to wait for the time given in delay function to perform kbhit() function actions.....**

```
while(1)
{
delay(1000);
if(kbhit()) 
{
//
//
//
//
}
}
```

//now i have to wait 1000ms to execute kbhit()'s code how to remove this problem..

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Google the concept "event-driven programming".

Comment: kbhit() is a "human time" function.  Humans can't detect when you delay(10), they will notice delay(1000).

Answer (score 0):

Please improve your way of asking!
Anyway I'll try to help you:
It seems you want to use [interrupts.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)

But in the most cases it's actually enough, to check keyboard inputs at a certain rate. E.g. a game that runs with 60FPS won't need more than 60 checks per second.
You may explain for what you need this way of keyhandling.